# How to use WHERE clause in INSERT query with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been reading other questions on this topic, but can't seem to get what I'm trying to do to work.

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO entries
(
    num_entries,
    m_d_y,
    last_entry
)
VALUES
(
    1,
    '01_24_2014',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_entries = (num_entries + 1), last_entry = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

The query works, but I want to add a condition WHERE the `UPDATE` is only executed IF `last_entry` is more than one second ago.

I tried adding a `WHERE` clause, but it didn't work because the `INSERT` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause.

Is there any way to add some sort of `WHERE` condition to my query?

The reason I'm trying to do it like this is that in my PHP code I'm checking to see if the query affected any rows. My goal here is to:

1. Insert a new row if it doesn't exist
2. Update the row if it does exist AND if the last entry was one second ago
3. To detect if the row was inserted or updated in PHP by checking to see if any rows were affected (which is why I'm trying to make the query like this)

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to include a `where` clause in an `insert ... on duplicate` instruction. Please read [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just change the query in the script language you're using? `last_entry` comes from that language (or now from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`), so you can add or omit the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part:

```
query = "INSERT INTO ...."
if less than a second ago:
  query += "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...."
```

Right?

Or do you mean the existing `last_entry` has to be > 1 sec old? That might be even easier?:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  num_entries = IF(last_entry-1 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), num_entries + 1, num_entries),
  last_entry = IF(last_entry-1 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), last_entry)
```

Or something like that? =)

(This is completely untested.)

Comment: The second code snipped you posted is exactly what I was just in the middle of trying! Yes, it works great, thanks!

Comment: Can you please take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154794/how-to-control-the-errors-in-on-duplicate-key-using-if-function), It is related with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do a INSERT SELECT like this contrived example:

```
INSERT INTO entries (col names)
Select 1, '01_24_2014', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE critera
ON DUPLICATE KeY UPDATE ...
```

MySQL Reference on this is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: But will that affect the case where the row already exists (i.e. prevent the UPDATE if less than one second has passed)?

Comment: If the key already exists, then that functionality would still work.  The MySQL Reference has a more thorough write-up on this.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried this method, but it only works when the row already exists. If the row doesn't exist, it doesn't create it.